# What cheat code do you use for spruce wood in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What is the cheat code for spruce wood in Minecraft on computer?
I know this part: `/give (player)`
but I don't know the rest.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The last argument to /give is the numerical "block id". You can look up block ids on any of the various Minecraft wikis. For example, https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spruce_wood#Data_values shows that Spruce Wood is block id 17.

Comment: Don't forget to precise the DV (Data Value) to 2, or else it will give Oak logs by default. More info about this command syntax at http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#give

Answer (score 2):

As of the newest versions of the game, your answer would be

`/give [USERNAME] minecraft:spruce_planks [COUNT]`

This is the more simplified version. It appears you, after about 4 years, should know how to get spruce planks by now, but this answer is to clarify for any new visitors wondering the same thing for newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

This command is just like giving yourself wood which would be `/give @p wood`
but to give yourself spruce or birch ext you would do `/give @p wood 1 1`
or `/give @p wood 1 2`.

Answer (score -1):

```
give @s log 64
```

I don't know if it's different for other versions, but this is for 1.12.

Answer (score -2):

It is

```
/give <player> <item> <amount>
```

For example, if I wanted 6 iron ingots, and my player was Jeff, I would write:

```
/give Jeff iron_ingot 6
```

Warning: Do not make the item plural otherwise it won't recognise the object.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.